# Export vector in .txt file with newline separator

Tags: export, format

I need to export a 1-D list (vector) in .txt format with one line corresponding to one value :

```
v = {v1, v2, v3, ..., vn};
```

And the result should be, in `filename.txt`:

```
v1
v2
v3
...
vn
```

I tried :

```
Export["filename.txt", v, "Table"];
```

But in get :

```
v1    v2    v3    ...    vn
```

Is it possible to get the correct format directly ? Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I get the correct output ! Are you sure ? The result should be a column or a line ? Also, you can check in the notebook what the output will be using [`ExportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html): compare what does `ExportString[v, "Table"]` and `ExportString[{v}, "Table"]`

Comment: Yes you were right : I was handling a matrix and trying to export it as a vector ! It is working now, thank you for the quick answers !